# CMake with Qt: moc creates .cpp_parameters ending

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, moc, qtimer

I am trying to integrate Qt in my project, especially QTimer.

Therefore, I have been trying to generate the moc files with cmake:

```
set(MOC_FILES
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../headerfile.h
)
set(HEADER_FILES
    ...
    ${MOC_FILES}
)
...

ivw_qt_wrap_cpp(MOC_FILES ${MOC_FILES})

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Create module
ivw_create_module(${SOURCE_FILES} ${SHADER_FILES} ${MOC_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES})
```

As a result it creates a file `moc_headerfile.cpp_parameters`, but the file should be `moc_volumeraycaster.cpp`.

The content of the file is this:

```
-DINVIWO_ALL_DYN_LINK
-DGLM_SHARED_BUILD
-DWIN32
-o
C:/../moc_headerfile.cpp
C:/..headerfile.h
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use the same variable as input and output for `qt_wrap_cpp`.

You could get rid of this using `AUTOMOC`:

```
set(SOURCE_FILES
    ...
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../headerfile.h
)
...

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Create module
ivw_create_module(${SOURCE_FILES} ${SHADER_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES})
```